# GWT Make synchronous / blocking call using Asynchronus Callback

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, gwt, synchronous

I have designed a class Lets call it AsyncClass which implements AsyncCalllback.
It has two global variables `boolean flag` and `Object val`.
And the constructor look like this:

```
AsyncClass()
{
    this.flag=false;
    this.val=null;
}
```

and `onSuccess()` function is defined as:

```
public void onSuccess(Object x){
      this.flag=true;
      this.val=x;
}
```

Now what I want is this to get a return value from here.
So I make a call:

```
AsyncClass callback=new AsyncClass();
service.getResult(createRequestObject(),callback)
```

and I have a while loop running which keeps waiting for the flag to turn true.

```
while(!callback.flag);
```

However it gets stuck in an infinite loop.
Why is this happening??

Comment: You will need to use the onFailure and onSuccess methods of the AsyncCallback. GWT is event driven so the call will succeed or fail and one of those methods will be called. Think of it as a call and forget, then wait for an event whether it is onSuccess or onFailure...

Comment: Which is exactly what I am doing. The onSuccess method is supposed to turn the flag on, so the while loop condition is met false and it exits. But the while loop keeps on going forever. Is it because the callback object is held by the current thread, and until it releases it nothing can happen ?

Comment: Correct - there is only one thread, so there is no way to even try to run the onSuccess until the code which has started the call to the server has returned control to the browser.

Comment: Any way around it? Using a parallel thread or something?

Comment: What does service.getResult do?

Comment: Are you trying to make your call synchron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous RPC Calls in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353310/synchronous-rpc-calls-in-gwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `Async` classes on advance with predefined `onSuccess` methods, you can just define them on the spot.
If you want to make an asynchronous call and then make use of the return value once the call succeeds, try this:

```
service.getResult(createRequestObject(), new AsyncCallback() {
    public void onSuccess(final Object returnedValue) {
        doSomethingWith(returnedValue);
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // code for the call failing (alert, log...)
    }
});
```

Better yet, if your service returns a certain type, like `String`, make use of the generic version of AsyncCallback instead of the raw one:

```
service.getResult(createRequestObject(), new AsyncCallback<String>() {
    public void onSuccess(final String returnedValue) {
        doSomethingWithString(returnedValue);
    }
    // onFail etc.
});
```

Once the call is made and if it succeeds, your `doSomethingWith` method will be called and the execution will continue from there.

---

EDIT: per OP's comments, it looks like they're trying to implement a **synchronous** call from client code, not an asynchronous one (despite the "Async" naming). I'm not sure that's possible using GWT's RPC library. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353310/synchronous-rpc-calls-in-gwt), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166942/gwt-synchronous-call), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729994/fake-a-gwt-synchronous-rpc-call), you'd have to implement the calls in pure Javascript via JSNI methods. However, you should notice that all the answers to those questions recommend to avoid synchronous calls and go asynchronous instead.

Comment: You are missing the point. I want to block, till I get a return value. The issue is since it is a single threaded system, the blocking mechanism doesn't allow the onSucess() to execute.

Comment: I'd say _you_ are the one missing the point if you are using **Async**Callback mechanism to implement a **synchronous** call. Anyways, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making is asynchronous, and you wish to make it work as if it were sync.
In my experience, this is not very practical, and you might want to refactor a little bit, like this:

```
some_code;
make_sync_call;
some_other_code;
```

into

```
some_code;
make_sync_call(new Receiver() {
   void onSuccess() {
      some_other_code;
   }
}
```

If there are solid reasons why you really need to make a busy wait instead of callback-based, then "javascript busy wait" are probably the keywords you're looking for (eg. here [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) )

Please note however that I strongly advise against it, and for the callback-based method.